# Deserialize property basing on another property

Tags: c#, datetime, json.net

The problem we are having is that our request model contains numerous properties of type `DateTime`. We need to be able to know what was the original timezone we have received in the request however as we all know `DateTime` is not storing that information. We cannot simply convert all our properties to `DateTimeOffset` because of the way the system is designed - it would casue a lot of troubles for our customers.

We know that every `DateTime` property in the request has the same Time zone. Our idea to workaround this issue is to add one additional property to the request model called `TimeZone` and populate it basing on the raw value of another property `StartDate`. In such scenario whenever we will need the original time zone of the `DateTime` property we will be able to construct it basing on the UTC value of the datetime property and persisted `TimeZone` property.
Is anyone able to point me to the right direction to achieve such goal ?
What we need is to be able to write some `JsonConverter` that will allow us to populate `TimeZone` property by reading the **raw** value of another property `StartDate`. Is it possible to write a simple `JsonConverter` that will be able to access another property while deserializing some property ?